# Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the List::MoreUtils module)

Tags: conda

I have installed abricate with conda, using the command

```bash
conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 abricate
```

When I run abricate I get the error

```bash
Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC 
  (you may need to install the List::MoreUtils module) 
  (@INC contains: 
    /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/bin/../perl5 
    /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
    /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0 
    /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/lib/perl5/5.22.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
    /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/lib/perl5/5.22.0 .) at 
  /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/bin/abricate line 9.
  
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
  /Users/JFF/opt/miniconda3/envs/abricate/bin/abricate line 9.
```

I have tried

```bash
conda install perl-list-moreutils
```

But when running the program again the error persists. Any idea how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use alternative labels (e.g., `bioconda/label/cf201901`). Also, Bioconda has [very specific channel requirements](http://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels). If you are a practicing bioinformatician, consider implementing them globally. Otherwise, for *ad hoc* installations, one should use:

```
## bioconda expects all those channels in that order every time
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults abricate
```

which is [exactly what the developer recommends](https://github.com/tseemann/abricate#bioconda).

Even better, modularize your software installations using different environments:

```
## create a new environment named "foo"
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults abricate
```